# Confusion regarding customs duty

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, india, import-taxes

I have come to Canada from India (Indian Resident) with 1 laptop, 1 tablet, 1 mobile and 1 DSLR as electronic goods. (Didn’t declare anything on paper, was not asked to, all goods were open without any box)

Here, in Canada I have purchased one laptop and one mobile.

I want to go back to India with all these goods, without their boxes.

1. I am a student and I have heard importing one laptop is customs free, does that apply if I already have one laptop beforehand?
2. Will I have to give customs duties on opened goods without any box? (2 laptops, 2 mobiles, 1 dslr, 1 keyboard, 1 ipad)

Please help!

Comment: Did you get and export certificate for your stuff when you left India ?

Comment: @Hilmar Unfortunately no. Didn’t know such a thing existed. But I have receipts of all the goods purchased in India. Does that help?

Comment: @Confused_oonga_boonga Sure, it will, but duty would likely still need to be paid on Canada's purchases

Comment: @NicolasFormichella India Custom Rules say I can take anything upto 50k to India duty free (that covers my phone) and one laptop over and above the free allowances can be imported duty free (page 3 I(A)(b) and page 4 note (5) on https://www.cbic.gov.in/resources/htdocs-cbec/guide_for_travellers/GUIDE_FOR_TRAVELLERS_v5.pdf)

Comment: @NicolasFormichella Can you please see the above links and tell me if my items will be duty free in all? And, should I go in green line or red line in such case?

Comment: If it's over the free allowances, it may or may not be mandatory to declare since there seems to be an exception for it. Better to take the red channel and declare your items, this way the worst that can happen is you pay duty, and if the exception applies to you you don't. If you take the green channel, and it turns out there is no exception, you will probably be fined additionally.